# cakephp2:How to get two different datas with different conditions from the same Model

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I'm new to cakephp2 and mysql and need some help.

I want to get the data from yesterday and daybefore yesterday date from the same Model in cakephp2,
However the conditions will be different so I am trying to get the data by  making two different methods that contains  the find()  with different conditions. ,however,I'ts not working. Here is the sample below ↓

This method getYesterday() will return the data as a array but I want to add a condition 
that will check if the pageview count is not 0, how will I do that ?

```
public function getYesterday() {

        $yes = array();
        $dt = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 day')); 
        //  $dy = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-2 day')); 
        $yesterday = $this->PvLog->find('all', array(
            'fields' => array('dt', 'params', 'count(params) as yesterday_pv'),
            'conditions' => array('dt' => "2014/09/26", 'is_crawler' => 0,'count(page_view)>'=>0), 
            'group' => array('params'),
            'order' => array('count(params)' => 'DESC'),
        ));

        foreach ($yesterday as $y) {
            $yes[] = $y;
            //$i++;
        }
        return $yes;
    }
```

The function below  will get the data from daybefore yesterday

```
public function getDBY() {
        $dayyes = array();
        $dt = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-2 day'));
        $daybefore = $this->PvLog->find('all', array(
            'fields' => array('dt', 'params', 'count(params) as daybefore_pv'),
            'conditions' => array('dt' => "{$dt}", 'is_crawler' => 0), 
            'group' => array('params'),
            'order' => array('count(params)' => 'DESC'),
        ));

        foreach ($daybefore as $dby) {
            $dayyes[] = $dby;
            //$i++;
        }

        return $dayyes;
    }
```

The probelem is I'm not sure about this way, Is there a better solution that you can get the different result with different conditions in mysql cakephp2 ?  The main thing I want to do Is to get the yesterdays data and daybefore yesterdays data from the same model but I'm  not sure how I can do this, I've checked cakes documents but cant find the solution. Sorry for my broken English.

Comment: Do you know the correct SQL needed to solve your problem?

Comment: if you're asking about a better way i would say : if you want to get the data in the same array so use just one query whith where condition dt = yesterday OR dt = before_yesterday , if you want it in differents array you have just the way you used different query . Remark : you don"t have to fetch the date if you use on it a condition ; it's an unused field...